# ML.net generic CustomMapping

Tags: c#, ml.net

I ma trying to do custom mapping in ML.net to use polynomial regression.
I have created a CustomMapping class that takes Input class as input and TransformInput class as output. What I need is to be able to set input and output classes as generic types that are specified or set at runtime.

```
[CustomMappingFactoryAttribute("Features")]
    public class PolynomialFeatures : CustomMappingFactory<Input, TransformOutput>
    {

        private readonly int _degree;
        public PolynomialFeatures(int degree)
        {
            _degree = degree;
        }

        public void Transform(Input input, TransformOutput output)
        {
            output.Features = Enumerable.Range(0, _degree + 1).Select(i => (float)(Math.Pow(input.Level, i))).ToArray();
            output.Salary = input.Salary;
        }

        public override Action<Input, TransformOutput> GetMapping()
        {
            return Transform;
        }

    }
```

and I am using this class like this:

```
var dataProcessPipeline = mLContext.Transforms.CustomMapping(polyFeatures.GetMapping(), contractName: null,inputSchemaDefinition: schema)

                                        .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", new[] { "Features" }));

            var trainer = mLContext.Regression.Trainers.Ols(featureColumnName: "Features", labelColumnName: "Salary");
            var trainingPipeline = dataProcessPipeline.Append(trainer);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read [the description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the [tag:ml] tag.

Comment: You cannot set a generic at runtime. Try using reflection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection